# Remember check box state when click back during NSIS installer

Tags: checkbox, nsis, back

I have a checkbox on one of my customer installer pages

```
${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 0 0 100% 15 "Check to run"
Pop $SvcCheckBox
CreateFont $0 "$(^Font)" "10"
SendMessage $SvcCheckBox ${WM_SETFONT} $0 1
GetFunctionAddress $0 OnCheckbox
nsDialogs::OnClick $SvcCheckBox $0
```

I want to remember this if the user comes back to this page.

I've used the code below to attempt this

```
${NSD_OnBack} "pageLeave"

FunctionEnd


Function pageLeave
    ${NSD_GetState} $SvcCheckBoxState $SvcCheckBox
FunctionEnd
```

However, if a user un-checks the box, goes to the next page, comes back to this page, the check box is checked again. I need it to remain unchecked.

How do I implement my pageLeave check box state on page load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need initialize the checkbox state when you create the page. You don't need a On* handler unless you want to update something else on the page when the checkbox changes.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh

Var CheckboxState
Var hCheckbox

Function .onInit
StrCpy $CheckboxState ${BST_CHECKED} ; Set initial/default state
FunctionEnd

Page Components
Page Custom MyPageCreate MyPageLeave
Page Components
Page InstFiles

Function MyPageCreate
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 0 0 100% 15 "Check to run"
Pop $hCheckbox
${NSD_SetState} $hCheckbox $CheckboxState

nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageLeave
${NSD_GetState} $hCheckbox $CheckboxState
FunctionEnd

Section
DetailPrint State=$CheckboxState
SectionEnd
```